# Cannot create service using bluemix CLI

Tags: ibm-cloud

I Tried creating cloudantNoSQLDB using below command

```
$ bx service create cloudantNoSQLDB Lite myCloudantDB
```

and it returns the below output with error

> Invoking 'cf create-service cloudantNoSQLDB Lite myCloudantDB'...
>
> Creating service instance myCloudantDB in org bluemixfun.net / space
>   WH as pravvyas@in.ibm.com... FAILED Server error, status code: 502,
>   error code: 10001, message: Service broker error: {"description"=>"The
>   instance cannot be provisioned in the environment requested."}
>
> pravvyas@pravvyas MINGW64 ~/nodejs-cloudant (master)

Comment: I see that you have an IBM email address listed in your error message. Is it possible that you are attempting to exceed the quota for the number of services in your account? Are you able to create other service instances? If you cannot create other service instances, you will need to open a ticket to request an internal allocation increase.

Comment: The maximum # of services in a trial account for an IBMer is 4. Please verify that this service instance would not exceed that number and, thus, could not be provisioned.

Comment: I had the same problem, and what William says was helpful. I removed 1 workspace and then it worked (apparently my account can only have 2 workspaces for now).